# Wordpress Portfolio Plugin

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery, portfolio

I am working with a Wordpress Site. I want to manage my projects record like a portfolio on the site. It must manage the project categories, detail and gallery. I want to show them by categories and if someone wants to view single project detail, a popup should appear with the project detail and the image.

Please let me know if there is a portfolio/gallery plugin? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please note: I am assuming here that you put `localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Home-Page1.jpg` in the Option->Image/Video URL field.

You missed the 'http://' part, Nimble Portfolio plugin use prettyPhoto for images and videos, and it expects a full path with protocol prefix.

You should put `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Home-Page1.jpg` instead of `localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Home-Page1.jpg`